# Google Cloud HTTP/HTTPs load balancer REFRESHING

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine

I have my application installed in 2 Ubuntu VMs running behind an HTTP/HTTPS Load balancer.
The load balancer is for some reason refreshing the connection, sometimes in couple of seconds, other times might after half hour.
Due to this refresh the user is moved out of the discussion in the application.

Any pointer on what might be going wrong.
Thanks alot

Comment: You should solve the session problem within your application, otherwise the whole concept of the load balancer is needless

Comment: I have installed the same application on aws with same elb settings, over there its working fine.
and i have tested individual VMs, working fine

Comment: So, everything is working fine or not? You should either configure the load balancer to use sticky sessions (such that a session of one user is always routed to the same backend server) or your application to share sessions (using memcache or putting the session into your database)

Comment: no in google its not working fine, the connection refreshes for some reason
I am using Generated cookie under session affinity section which according to the description should stick a user to one instance.